# Placeholder for textarea? (ExtJS)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Is there placeholder for textarea? ([ExtJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an `emptyText` config option in [`Ext.form.TextArea`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea).

**Documentation:**

> The default text to place into an empty field (defaults to null). Note: that this value will be submitted to the server if this field is enabled and configured with a name.

**Documentation for Ext 4.2.2:**

> The default text to place into an empty field.
>
> Note that normally this value will be submitted to the server if this field is enabled; to prevent this you can set the `submitEmptyText` option of `Ext.form.Basic.submit` to false.
>
> Also note that if you use `inputType: 'file'`, emptyText is not supported and should be avoided.
>
> Note that for browsers that support it, setting this property will use the HTML 5 placeholder attribute, and for older browsers that don't support the HTML 5 placeholder attribute the value will be placed directly into the input element itself as the raw value. This means that older browsers will obfuscate the `emptyText` value for password input fields.

Answer (score 2):

**Use this:-**

```
xtype: 'textfield',
placeHolder: 'Please Enter Something'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `emptyText` attribute

```
xtype: 'textfield',
label: 'Try KeyDown',
emptyText: 'Press Enter/Return here...',
name: 'email',
animateUnderline : true
```

Comment: How is this different from the first answer?

Comment: I just tryed to share a peace of code, it is not different

Answer (score 1):

According to HTML5 drafts, you can use the `placeholder` attribute in a `textarea` element. This is independent of JavaScript. Did you mean something else?

Browser support to the `placeholder` attribute is still rather limited. On the other hand, there is seldom any need for a placeholder in a textarea, if the area is preceded by a descriptive label, as it should.

Comment: It won't work with IE7. The placeholder that I mean has to be a part of ExtJS library.

Answer (score 0):

emptyText config option works, as pointed out by @e-zinc. However, it doesn't clear out the value. Here is a fix.

```
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    me.on('focus', function () {
        if(!me.isDirty()) {
            me.setValue('');
        }
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```